# Reusable responsive VR (Vertical Rule) HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a reusable VR (Vertical Rule, like a `<hr>`, but vertical) component using HTML and CSS.

Maybe my requirements are impossible to achieve with the current state of HTML and CSS, but hopefully it's just my lack of experience/knowledge that's the real issue here.

### Requirements

- It should ideally be just an empty div `<div class="vr"></div>` with some CSS to correctly style it `.vr { ... }`.
- The div should be the width of the line.

  - e.g. If the line has a width of 2px, then the div should total 2px width.
- It should be responsive, and dynamically fill it's parent's height.

  - i.e. The height should not be fixed at a static value.
- It should be self contained and not require elements to be to the left or right of it.

  - e.g. Not putting a border on the preceding or following element.
- It should work in IE11+.

  - Flexbox is fine, and is used in the sample code below.
- It should work within an app making heavy use of bootstrap and flexbox.
- No JavaScript.

  - I'm comfortable with JavaScript, and I'm confident I could write something to watch the parent and manually set the height when the parent height changes. But this shouldn't be needed for "basic" styling/layout.

### What I've tried

There's quite a few suggestions on SO alone, and even more spread over the rest of the internet. But these suggestions are often old, and frequently use techniques that are inflexible.

- `.vr`

  - I naively thought I could simply give the div a `border-left` but nothing is displayed.
- `vr-fixedheight`

  - Setting a fixed height works, but it needs to be responsive to fit the different places it'll be used.
- `.vr-100pheight`

  - I tried explicitly saying the height is 100%, even though with flexbox that shouldn't be needed, and it still didn't render anything.
- `&nbsp;`

  - I tried setting the content of the div to be `&nbsp;` but this creates "dead space" in the div. i.e. the line is 2px wide, but the div is ~7px wide total.
- `vr-d-inlineblock`

  - Using `display: inline-block` was suggested. I don't think that should matter inside a flexbox, and setting it still didn't render the line.

I've put together a jsFiddle showing what I've tried: https://jsfiddle.net/758dn6ph/

And here's a paste of the code in case jsFiddle is not available to you:

```
<div class="test d-flex flex-row align-items-center border p-2 bg-dark text-light">
  <span>One</span>
  <div class="vr"></div>
  <span>Two</span>
  <div class="vr-fixedheight"></div>
  <span>Three</span>
  <div class="vr-100pheight"></div>
  <span>Four</span>
  <div class="vr">&nbsp;</div>
  <span>Five</span>
  <div class="vr-d-inlineblock"></div>
  <span>Six</span>
</div>
```

```css
/* These classes are (failed) attempts at making the VR div "work" */
.vr {
  background: yellow;
  border-left: 2px solid magenta;
}

.vr-fixedheight {
  height: 10px;

  background: yellow;
  border-left: 2px solid magenta;
}

.vr-100pheight {
  height: 100%;

  background: yellow;
  border-left: 2px solid magenta;
}

.vr-d-inlineblock {
  display: inline-block;

  background: yellow;
  border-left: 2px solid magenta;
}

/* These classes a purely for making the example easier to see, and are not part of the VR */

.test span:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.test span:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

NOTE: Bootstrap 4 is being used in the example, and the target app. It's already linked in the jSFiddle, but you'll have to pull it in manually if you use the raw code.

Comment: Note that you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to recreate what you've done on jsFiddle here on Stack Overflow. You can provide a link to a [Bootstrap CDN](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/) to pull that into the snippet.

Comment: The reason it doesn't show with `.vr` is cause the div is empty so it collapses to a height of zero. `height` is a percentage of width so you need to look into that issue. I didn't. Most of us use `border` to do what you want.

Comment: Because I can, note that `<hr>` does not use, and browsers ignore, a closing slash in HTML.

Comment: @Rob I removed the trailing slash and corrected the bootstrap tag to bootstrap 4. Thanks for the pointers.